# JSF converter with null value

Tags: jsf, converters, bigdecimal

I need to convert `null` property values of type `java.math.BigDecimal` to `0.00` everywhere with a specified number of decimal places (only for displaying (`<h:outputText>`) thus, not for input components).

The basic converter expected to do this job is given below (currency, percentage, locale etc have been excluded completely for brevity).

```
@FacesConverter("bigDecimalConverter")
public final class BigDecimalConverter implements Converter {

    private static final int SCALE = 2;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {

        if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return new BigDecimal(submittedValue).setScale(SCALE, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "Message"), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {

        BigDecimal value;

        if (modelValue == null) { // This is expected to replace null with 0.
            value = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        } else if (modelValue instanceof Long) {
            value = BigDecimal.valueOf((Long) modelValue);
        } else if (modelValue instanceof Double) {
            value = BigDecimal.valueOf((Double) modelValue);
        } else if (!(modelValue instanceof BigDecimal)) {
            throw new ConverterException("Message");
        } else {
            value = (BigDecimal) modelValue;
        }

        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
        numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(SCALE);
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(SCALE);
        return numberFormat.format(value);
    }
}
```

Referring to a property of the associated model or bean of type `java.math.BigDecimal` using output components like the following.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}">
    <f:converter converterId="bigDecimalConverter"/>
</h:outputText>
```

`bean.value` is a type of `java.math.BigDecimal` in a managed bean. If `bean.value` is `null`, then the `getAsString()` method is not invoked. Hence, an empty output is rendered where a value of zero is expected.

This `value="#{bean.value}"` needs to be changed to `value="#{empty bean.value ? 0 : bean.value}"` for the converter to perform its coherent task.

Putting this conditional test in EL everywhere is however, quite maintenance-unfriendly.

Is there a way to invoke the `getAsString()` method, when a target property is `null` which is conditionally attempted to be set to `0` in that method (`BigDecimal.ZERO`)?

---

**Update :**

The `getAsString()` method is invoked with `<o:param>` (OmniFaces).

```
<h:outputFormat value="Discount ({0}%)">
    <o:param value="#{bean.value}">
        <f:converter converterId="bigDecimalConverter"/>
    </o:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

This displays `Discount (0.00%)` after has been converted by the converter, when `#{bean.value}` returns `null`.

Comment: It would be useful to have the JSF impl-version provided.

Comment: It is Mojarra 2.2.12. Tested on Apache Tomcat 8.0.27.0, GlassFish 4.1 and WildFly 10.0.0 final alternatively.

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to the Mojarra. The problem occurred because the converter is not called when the value is null (see [source here](https://github.com/bleathem/mojarra/blob/master/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/HtmlBasicRenderer.java#L356)). I tested the same code in the MyFaces implementation and the result is that the convert is always called, no matter if the value is null (as can be seen [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/myfaces/shared/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/shared/renderkit/RendererUtils.java?view=markup), line 378).

So if change JSF implementation is not an option, I think the solution through OmniFaces is good enough. At worst, maintain a function that makes the conversion like `#{convert(bean.value)}` may leave cleaner your view than an inline comparison.

Comment: What way is recommended by OmniFaces to defend against this particular issue?

Comment: OmniFaces has its own [implementation of param](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/component/output/Param.java#L120), the [o:param](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/param), which also calls the converter no matter the value is null. So you can use this component to convert as you demonstrated in the update of your question. But if you want a simple conversion to show the value as it is, I think that a function like `#{bean.convertNullAsZero(bean.value)}` would do the job more simply and clearly.