# How to have a custom non null value for empty input component dispite INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL = true

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my `faces-config.xml` I have set

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
 <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Thus an arbitrary input component with no input places a `null` into the bean property bound to the `value="#{myBean.someDate}"` attribute and renders an empty component when getting `null` from that bean property.

While this is generally the wanted behavior for the application, I have a particular component where I want to replace `null` with a custom `non null` value.

**Is there a general good way to achieve this?**

I have tried this for the Primefaces (6.2) calendar with Mojarra 2.3.8:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
        <p:calendar value="#{myBean.someDate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
            converter="mySpecialDateConverter" locale="en" />
        <p:commandButton value="send" process="@form" update="@form" />
        <hr />
        <h:outputText value="#{myBean.someDate}" />
</h:form>
```

I tried it using a converter that while rendering the component returns an `empty String` in `getAsString()` when my custom value is received from `#{myBean.someDate}`, or spits out my custom value in `getAsObject()` when `null` or pure emptyness is submitted:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter("mySpecialDateConverter")
public class MyConverter extends DateTimeConverter {

    private static final Date PAST = new Date(0);

    public MyConverter() {
        setPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (PAST.equals(value)) {
            return "";
        }
        return super.getAsString(context, component, value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (null == value || "".equals(value.trim())) {
            return PAST;
        }
        return super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
    }

}
```

Rendering an empty calendar component when the bean property equals `PAST` works as expected. But submitting the calender without input sets the property to `null` because Primefaces `CalendarRenderer` simply does not consult the `Converter` on blank value submission:

```
package org.primefaces.component.calendar;

public class CalendarRenderer extends InputRenderer {
    // ...
    public Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ConverterException {
        Calendar calendar = (Calendar) component;
        String submittedValue = (String) value;
        SimpleDateFormat format = null;

        if (isValueBlank(submittedValue)) {
            return null;
        }

        //Delegate to user supplied converter if defined
        try {
            Converter converter = calendar.getConverter();
            if (converter != null) {
                return converter.getAsObject(context, calendar, submittedValue);
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

This is partially ok, as the JavaDoc on `Converter.getAsObject()` says:

```
/** 
 * @return <code>null</code> if the value to convert is <code>null</code>, 
 * otherwise the result of the conversion 
 */
```

Such there is no reason for Primefaces to resolve the converter on empty input. Would be different imho if we'd set `javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL = false`. Then I'd consider above behavior not correct as `""` is not `null`.

For completeness this is my bean aka `myBean`:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Date someDate;

    public Date getSomeDate() {
        return someDate;
    }

    public void setSomeDate(Date someDate) {
        this.someDate = someDate;
    }

}
```

I don't want to make changes to that bean as in real application the Calendars' value is bound to persisted entity property values. I also don't want the persistence layer do the job.

**The very background:**

I want to prevent `null` values in some database `DATE` fields. In case of periods for example I want the start default to some far away past date not relevant in application context, for end of that period I want a date in the far future not relevant in application context and both without to bother the user which dates they are by default. These default dates help filtering entities for which the current `Date` is in or out of that period, while no input by the user is assumed to be virtually the period `for ever`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF components will not call the converter on a null value or anything they considers as null - this is true for the default components in JSF as well. So in this regard I guess PrimeFaces is behaving as expected and this is the correct outcome. Here are two ways of circumventing this that instantly come to mind;

### Use OmniFaces

As described in [JSF converter with null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347001/jsf-converter-with-null-value), OmniFaces `o:param` will call your converter regardless of a null value - you can use it to pass parameters to components. In your specific case you should be able to do something similar to this;

```
<h:form id="myForm">
        <p:calendar value="#{myBean.someDate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" locale="en" />
        <p:commandButton value="send" process="@form" update="@form">
            <o:param name="date" value="#{myBean.someDateConversion}"
                     converter="mySpecialDateConverter" /> 
        </p:commandButton>
        <hr />
        <h:outputText value="#{myBean.someDate}" />
</h:form>
```

### Use a custom renderer

The second option is to use a custom renderer and just modify the behaviour of the component to always call the converter, as described in this answer - [JSF Custom Converter not called on null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048438/jsf-custom-converter-not-called-on-null-value).

Comment: Thank you for assisting - the o:param seemes to only handle the **output** direction using a converter to get the correct String via `Converter.getAsString()` for rendering which already worked for me. It does not seem to pipe submitted values through `Converter.getAsObject()` into the bean property from user **input**. So you think I'll have to override the renderer? Your both links have the same target URL btw.

Comment: @Selaron Sorry about that. Modified the second link. For handling empty input - both methods should work for your purposes. `o:param` won't call getAsObject() obviously - instead, the idea is to handle this in the setter method it calls and read this value from the parent component. It's a simple way to "force" the conversion. Depending on your goal you might not even have to bother with the converter here in o:param - just using a normal `f:param` or `f:attribute` probably works just fine.

Comment: @Selaron And to answer your question - to really rely and make sure the converter is called by JSF for you - as far as I know you have to modify it's behavior as described above. The other option is to work around it, as discussed.

Comment: I ended up creating a custom renderer that overrides `CalendarRenderer.getConvertedValue` in a similar way as described in [the Q/A linked by your](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048438/jsf-custom-converter-not-called-on-null-value). Thank you.